# How can I command a WebView in a fragment from another class?

Tags: android, webview, fragment

Basically I have a WebView in a fragment and there is a java class which checks the network availability. I can make toast messages for both true and false conditions. But as the WebView is in another fragment, I cannot make it load a URL. Thus my question is:
How can I call an item from another class?

Edit:

```
package com.sahin.spm;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.widget.Toast;
import layout.fragHome;

/**
 * Created by PD on 27.1.2017.
 */
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Connection control";
    static boolean isConnected = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        isNetworkAvailable(context);

    }


    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                        if(!isConnected){ 
                            isConnected = true;
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            fragHome.loadWebViewUrl("http://www.google.com.tr");

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        isConnected = false;
        Toast.makeText(context, "No connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        fragHome.loadWebViewUrl("file:///android_asset/noconnection.html");
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my class in which I control the connection and want the webview to load a page according to connection status. There is no error but this way it doesn't load.

fragHome.java

```
package layout;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.sahin.spm.NetworkChangeReceiver;
import com.sahin.spm.R;


public class fragHome extends Fragment {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Auto control";
    private NetworkChangeReceiver receiver;
    private static WebView webView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_home, container, false);

        final WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hWebView);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }
        });


        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);


        return rootView;

    }
    public static void loadWebViewUrl(String url) {
        if (webView != null) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { 
        super.onDestroy();

        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);

    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, Put fragHome code also.

Comment: Added. @A.Badakhshan

Comment: Is user in fragHome when NetworkChangeReceiver triggers?

Comment: Yes, it is in the first activity after the splash screen. 
loadWebViewUrl does not load a page even in fragHome itself. (I tried changin webView.loadUrl line to loadWebViewUrl and it didn't work) @A.Badakhshan

Comment: You have declared a final WebView with exact same name of static one in your onCreateView. Remove the two words of "final WebView".

Comment: Worked great!!! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Plz vote up my answer too if you can. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way would be using an static `WebView` and call loading of its url using an static method or directly.

**EDIT:**

```
public class WebViewerFragment extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private static WebView webView;

    public WebViewerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_viewer, container, false);

        WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

        return rootView;
    }

    public static void loadWebViewUrl(String url) {
        if (webView != null) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can call `loadWebViewUrl` method from anywhere like this:

```
WebViewerFragment.loadWebViewUrl(desiredUrl);
```

But the important thing that you should be cautious about that is `webView` instance shouldn't be `null`,  so `WebViewerFragment` must be initialized before calling this method.

Comment: I am just a beginner. Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: I don't know the reason of down vote, but if you didn't solved your problem, let me know and I will explain it for you.

Comment: I didn't vote it deliberately but I might have clicked accidentaly, sorry for that. I didn't solve the problem. I will be glad if you can explain it.

Comment: @ŞahinAygünYıldırım I edited my answer. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Static views are bad, because it's effectively a Context leak, that's why I downvoted.  A better way to do this would be to use the Fragment's bundle arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalBroadcastManager or EventBus library.

On webview fragment just listen for broadcast/event and load the url then.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it.